# Facebook Page Tab - IFrame

Tags: facebook, iframe

I'm really stuck with Facebook Page Tab, that I've built using PHP-SDK. I've developed my pages, authorization stuff, admin page etc. but when it comes to put the tab in the page, my pagetab doesn't show the content. Yes, from applications I've chosen Page Tab, added urls, admin urls, but still it doesn't show it. I thought that it may be caused by ssl requirement. Domain that I've developed page under, doesn't have an ssl certificate. Even though it doesn't have, I think page tab has to show the page when I turn off the secure browsing, right? But it doesn't. Is there anything I miss? I might, because I'm pretty new in Facebook development.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your app page directly with SSL? Just type into the browser https://YOUR APP_URL

Comment: Yes, and it says cannot connect to webpage. I did this, but I'm saying that even though it doesn't work, when i disable secure browsing, it should be there, right?

Comment: Facebook always access to app via https, so you have to fix this issue first.

Comment: Ok thanks. I think I'll move my app to Heroku first, so that I can get free ssl, too.